# Qt Creator как правильно задать класс QXmlSimpleReader?

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Понадобилось преобразить XML документ к SAX представлению.
Документация на Qt предлагает использовать QXmlSimpleReader
Но мне не удалось правильно подключить этот класс, Qt Creator ругается

Как подключить QXmlSimpleReader и пропарсить XML документ?

Ответ простой и очевидный: RTFM
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlsimplereader.html

Записал в файле моего проекта *.pro: "QT += xml"

Записал в заголовочном файле файле *.h: "#include "

Создал в файле *.cpp класс: "QXmlSimpleReader xmlReader;"

Запустил, работает.

Спасибо, asianirish

Comment: Возможно вы забыли `qmake: QT += xml`, то есть (если используется этот тип проекта) в `.pro` файле следует добавить строчку `QT += xml`. Ну и, конечно, в соответствующим месте подключить `#include <QXmlSimpleReader>`. Все должно заработать

Comment: Да, все так. Спасибо.